# I am filtering a multilevel NSArray using NSPredicate., i am trying to filter 3rd child of array using predicate but i am getting this

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array, filter, nspredicate

Unable to parse the format string "json.option_titles.ANY.options.ANY.jobID == %@

Although i can use the for loop but i might have option titles length long so it will be not good. will it be possible using nspredicate?
This is my sample Data

```
(
{
    dept = 1194;
    id = 2299;
    job = 22048;
    json =     {
        name = tester;
        "option_titles" =         (
                        {
                "custom_option_title" = "";
                "financing_option" = "";
                options =                 (
                                        {
                        hours = "2.00";
                        jobID = 22048;
                        optionDesc = "Sample Description";
                    },
                                        {
                        hours = "2.00";
                        jobID = 22048;
                        optionDesc = "Sample Description";
                    },
                );

            }
        );
        "system_observations" = "";
    };
    name = tester;
    "sort_order" = 178;
    "system_observations" = "";
},
{
    dept = 1195;
    id = 2300;
    job = 22000;
    json =     {
        name = tester second;
        "option_titles" =         (
                        {
                "custom_option_title" = "title option";
                "financing_option" = "";
                options =                 (
                                        {
                        hours = "2.00";
                        jobID = 22000;
                        optionDesc = "Sample Description";
                    },
                                        {
                        hours = "2.00";
                        jobID = 22000;
                        optionDesc = "Sample Description";
                    },
                );

            }
        );
        "system_observations" = "";
    };
    name = tester;
    "sort_order" = 179;
    "system_observations" = "";
}
)
```

Tried Code:-

```
 NSArray *allJobs = [self getAllJobs];
                allJobs = [allJobs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dept_id == %@)",deptId]];

                NSMutableArray *coumpoArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                for (NSDictionary *job in allJobs) {
                    NSPredicate *predicateDeepFilterJobID = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"json.option_titles.options.jobID == %@",job[@"id" ]];
                    [coumpoArray addObject:predicateDeepFilterJobID];
                }

                NSPredicate *pr = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:coumpoArray];
                filterBydept = [arrayTemplate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pr];
```

Tried another predicate:-

```
 NSArray *allJobs = [self getAllJobs];
                allJobs = [allJobs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dept_id == %@)",deptId]];

                NSMutableArray *coumpoArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                for (NSDictionary *job in allJobs) {
                    NSPredicate *predicateDeepFilterJobID = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"json.option_titles.ANY.options.ANY.jobID == %@",job[@"id" ]];
                    [coumpoArray addObject:predicateDeepFilterJobID];
                }

                NSPredicate *pr = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:coumpoArray];
                filterBydept = [arrayTemplate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pr];
```

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: added the sample code